# nuget and tfs 2013 build, sharepoint 2013 package can not find assembly

Tags: sharepoint, nuget, tfsbuild

Assume we have the following project structure:

```
D:\workspace\Internet\Web
Web.sln
 -> Project A
 -> Project B
 -> CommonSharePointProject X
   -> uses and packages Newtonsoft.Json (for example)

D:\workspace\Common
CommonLibraries.sln
 -> CommonSharePointProject X
   -> uses and packages Newtonsoft.Json
 -> Common Library Y
 -> Common Library Z
```

My problem is, the commonly used library.
The packages directory will be created under the solution's directory.
And deployments from Visual Studio work just fine.
CommonLibrary X has a reference to newtonsoft.json.dll in the Web\packages... folder.

**TFS Build however expects the newtonsoft.json.dll to be in CommonLibraries\packages.
Why is that? And how do I solve this problem?**

The error is as follows:
**D:\ws_build\1\CMP04\Buildname\src\Common\SharePoint\Something\Main\CommonSharePointLibrary\Package\Package.package: The following file can not be found: "D:\ws_build\1\CMP04\BuildName\src\Common\SharePoint\Something\Main\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll".**

...the build process builds D:\ws_build\1\CMP04\Buildname\src\Internet\Web\web.sln.
So why doesn't it look for the assembly in internet\web\packages rather than common...\packages?

The SharePoint package references the 3rd party assembly using a relative path: "..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll". So obviously in TFSBuild the relativ path points somewhere different than in Visual Studio.

Also assuming I had another solution... where would CommonSharePointProject's reference to Newtonsoft.Json point to? As the project is used in multiple solutions I cannot have different references to different packages folders in every solution. There is only one .csproj file.

```
D:\workspace\Intranet\OtherWeb
OtherWeb.sln
-> OtherProject A
-> OtherProject B
-> CommonSharePointProject X
  -> uses and packages Newtonsoft.Json
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you "Enable package restore" already enable?

If you have it (Right click in your solution -> Enable packages restore). Then, "nuget package restore" will ensure to download all the needed packages in order to build your solution. And this way you can forget about the packages.

You don´t need to upload your packages to tfs, in fact the folder should be empty, only with the packages.config, because he will read this file to download the needed packages.

**EDIT**:
If your problem is that you have projects in one solution, that already have their own solution and you are getting a reference error, try to install this package:

NuGetReferenceHintPathRewrite
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGetReferenceHintPathRewrite

Install this in all the projects in your solution. This will help with reference problems ;) Or at least I hope so

Comment: I already have that in place. Both package restore and only packages.config in my source controlled packages folders. It doesn't help with multiple references to the same .csproj.

Comment: Unfortunately not - I added the nuget package you mentioned to every nuget-enabled project within the solution. Still no luck. It appears to be SharePoint related though as it cannot *package* the assembly. (It does compile just fine.)

Comment: Try to add this package to every project, not only to those which need nuget. And another thing, how have you added the references? When you click in Add reference -> there is Project and Browse. You need to add them from project, if you browse, the reference will not point to the csproj, if you add it from project yes, it wil lpoint to the csproj. Sorry, I have no more ideas

Comment: As I said it compilation works fine and the nuget packages are being downloaded. The only thing not working with tfs build (in contrast to visual studio) is the sharepoint project packaging mechanism. It points to the wrong packages folder :(